# Can we configure logins to only connect to read-only replicas in Azure SQL Database automatically?

Tags: sql-server, logins, read-only-database, azure-sql-managed-instance, read-only-routing

For Read-Only routing, rather than explicitly using "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" into our application connection string or for individual users to specify it in additional properties, can this be configured while creating a login?

For Example: Any user trying to connect to the instance should be routed to read-only replica, even if they don not provide "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" in their connection string.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No.  But you can disable their logins on the instance that normally hosts the primary replica and have them connect directly to an instance that normally hosts a read-only replica.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @David
By what you say does it mean, we might have access to the secondary read-only replica is it? If it is so we can create the logins in read-only replica rather than the primary server? 
My understanding was we cannot access them, but, whatever logins we create in primary server only gets replicated in the read-only copy.

Comment: Logins are instance-level principals, and so are not replicated by the AG.  Database Users are replicated.

Comment: I do replicate the logins manually for the fail over DR instance, but I believe as per the below doc, by default, we have read-only instance/replicas which the connections hit when we provide "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly". That is what I was not sure if we can make it a default setting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/read-scale-out

Comment: No.  There's no way to force ReadIntent for particular users.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs